# Meta Box WP_Query array for showing items with a certain relationship

Tags: wp-query, metabox

in oxygen I am using a repeater to show posts that have a certain relationship. The advanced query in the relationship is post_type = "custom post type1" and then I add another parameter that is post_in = ... I then go into the meta box field and select my relationship "custom post type1 to"

It then displays all posts in the "custom post type1" that have a direct relationship with the current post (a post within "custom post type2"). Works great until I need to use a bunch of repeaters on a single post.

I decided I would just go ahead and work on my own WP_Query to be able to set up pagination for each one instead of using a repeater. I also am looking at possible using piotnet grid for this as it has a custom query option that allows you to insert a wp_query array.

My problem is while I know how to do the array i don't know how to insert the relationship check.

```
array("post_type" => "custom post type1", "post_in" => "???");
```

Any help would be grateful as I have tried googling but can't seem to find anything (it is late for me so might be why I haven't found anything sorry if its painfully obvious as to what to do).

Answer (score 0):

Alright so after waking up and actually thinking (lol) it was quite simple and I was way overthinking it.

In piotnet grid you can query a custom wp_query. I added this to the box

```
array(relationship => [
        //the meta box relationship id
        'id' => 'relationship-between-cpt1&cpt2',
        'from' => get_the_ID(),
    ])
```

in the preview window on piotnet grid it will look broke but once you put it into a post it works just fine.